# Why was my question about skeletal animation blending closed for needing... debugging details?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-closed, debugging-questions

This is the link: [How do I correctly blend between skeletal animations in OpenGL from a walk animation to a run animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69860756/how-do-i-correctly-blend-between-skeletal-animations-in-opengl-from-a-walk-anima)

I left it there for a few days, came back, posted an answer, then found a blue banner on it saying: **"This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers."**

What happened? I've seen *a lot* of questions like this.

I edited it, checked the "Submit for review" checkbox, then it got closed again.

> This post was edited and submitted for review yesterday and failed to
> reopen the post:
>
> Original close reason(s) were not resolved
>
> (Private feedback for you)

Comment: It looks like it's been reopened now.